# Find unmatched rows between two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, gaps-and-islands

Given this setup:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (column1 text, column2 text);
CREATE TABLE table2 (column1 text, column2 text);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
   ('A', 'A')
 , ('B', 'N')
 , ('C', 'C')
 , ('B', 'A');

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES
   ('A', 'A')
 , ('B', 'N')
 , ('C', 'X')
 , ('B', 'Y');
```

How can I find ***missing combinations*** of `(column1, column2)` between these two tables? Rows not matched in the other table.

The desired result for the given example would be:

```
  C | C
  B | A
  C | X
  B | Y
```

There can be duplicate entries so we'd want to omit those.

Comment: For an unambiguous answer you should declare whether there can be NULL values and, if so, how to deal with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is `union all`:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2
from t1
where (t1.col1, t1.col2) not in (select t2.col1, t2.col2 from t2)
union all
select t2.col1, t2.col2
from t2
where (t2.col1, t2.col2) not in (select t1.col1, t1.col2 from t1);
```

If there are duplicates *within* a table, you can remove them by using `select distinct`.  There is no danger of duplicates *between* the tables.

Answer (score 3):

The **devil is in the details** with this seemingly simple task.

Short and among the fastest:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM        (SELECT col1, col2, TRUE AS x1 FROM t1) t1
FULL   JOIN (SELECT col1, col2, TRUE AS x2 FROM t2) t2 USING (col1, col2)
WHERE  (x1 AND x2) IS NULL;
```

The [`FULL [OUTER] JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html) includes all rows from both sides, but fills in NULL values for columns of missing rows. The `WHERE` conditions `(x1 AND x2) IS NULL` identifies these unmatched rows. Equivalent: `WHERE x1 IS NULL OR x2 IS NULL`.

To eliminate **duplicate** pairs, add `DISTINCT` (or `GROUP BY`) at the end - cheaper for ***few*** dupes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2
FROM ...
```

If you have ***many*** dupes on either side, it's cheaper to fold *before* the join:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM        (SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, TRUE AS x1 FROM t1) t1
FULL   JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, TRUE AS x2 FROM t2) t2 USING (col1, col2)
WHERE  (x1 AND x2) IS NULL;
```

It's more complicated if there can be **NULL values**. `DISTINCT` / `DISTINCT ON` or `GROUP BY` treat them as equal (so dupes with NULL values are folded in the subqueries above). But `JOIN` or `WHERE` conditions must evaluate to `TRUE` for rows to pass. NULL values are ***not*** considered equal in this, the `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` never finds a match for pairs containing NULL. This may or may not be desirable. You just have to be aware of the difference and define your requirements.

Consider the added demo in the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a9ef3/2)

**If** there are no NULL values, no duplicates, but an additional column defined `NOT NULL` in each table, like the primary key, let's name each `id`, then it **can be as simple as**:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM   t1
FULL   JOIN t2 USING (col1, col2)
WHERE  t1.id IS NULL OR t2.id IS NULL;
```

Related:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)
- [PostgreSQL - Create table as select with distinct on specific columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166955/postgresql-create-table-as-select-with-distinct-on-specific-columns/166982#166982)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `not exists` with a subquery, then use `UNION ALL`

```
select Column1,Column2   from table1 t1 
where NOT exists 
(
    select 1 
    FROM table2 t2
    where t1.Column1 = t2.Column1 or t1.Column2 = t2.Column2
)
UNION ALL
select Column1,Column2  from table2 t1 
where NOT exists 
(
    select 1 
    FROM table1 t2
    where t1.Column1 = t2.Column1 or t1.Column2 = t2.Column2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try set operations. `EXCEPT` to find the rows in table but not in the other and `UNION` to put the partial results into one.

```
(SELECT column1,
        column2
        FROM table1
 EXCEPT
 SELECT column1,
        column2
        FROM table2)
UNION
(SELECT column1,
        column2
        FROM table2
 EXCEPT
 SELECT column1,
        column2
        FROM table1);
```

If you don't need duplicate elimination you can try to use the `ALL` variants (`EXCEPT ALL` and `UNION ALL`). They are generally faster, as the DBMS doesn't have to look for and eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a perfect task for set operations:

```
  ( --all rows from table 1 missing in table 2
    select *
    from table1
    except 
    select *
    from table2
  )
  union all -- both select return distinct rows
  ( -- all rows in table 2 missing in table 1
    select *
    from table2
    except 
    select *
    from table1
  )
```